# Transform JSON Response Field Name In Mongoose Model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My JSON response contains a field first_name but I want my Mongoose model to represent this field as firstName. Is this possible and if so then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object with different property names from the one Mongoose returns. A nice way of doing this is to create a transform function. For example, let's say this is your schema:

```
{
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

Then you can use this function to create a new object with the desired property names:

```
function transformDocument (doc) {
  return {
    first_name: doc.firstName,
    last_name: doc.lastName
  }
}
```

Then, when you query the DB, you apply this function to the response:

```
Person.findOne({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' })
    .then(transformDocument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doug W has a good solution, but if you don't want to be using Promises and chaining  `.then`s, then you can simply add options to the schema like this:

```js
const mongoose = require ('mongoose'); // I am using v5.9.1 at the moment

const { Schema } = mongoose.Schema;

// Specify an options object
const options = {
    toJSON: {
        versionKey: false
    }
    // If you ever send the query result as an object,
    // you may remove it from there, too, if you wish
    // toObject: {
    //     versionKey: false
    // }
};

// Attach the options object to the schema by 
// passing it into Schema as the second argument
const mySchema = new Schema({
    /** define your schema */
}, options);
```

This will still save __v to the document in the database. But it will not appear on the json/object when it is the result of a mongoose query.

Besides setting `versionKey: false` in the options, you may also specify a transform function:

```js
/* ... */
// Specify an options object
const options = {
    toJSON: {
        // versionKey: false,
        transform: function(doc, ret) {
            // ret is the object that will be returned as the result
            // (and then stringified before being sent)
            delete ret.__v;
            return ret;
        }
    }
};
/* ... */
```

I know this question is nearly two years old, but I needed an answer to this question, and google was not kind to me at the time. I figured it out, and now I'm hoping someone else will be looking for an answer here and find that they have options. Pun not originally intended.